# Visual Studio 2013 crashes when compiling Sqlite C++ library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

I'm having an absolute nightmare of a time trying to get the Sqlite C++ library to compile in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate (Compiles fine in VS2012).

Basically regardless of whether I try to perform a clean or a rebuild VS will claim to successfully finish but will subsequently freeze and become unresponsive, never to recover.

Here is the output

[image: Output]

and [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33166191/sqlite-core.7z) is the actual VS project.

Anyone care to give it a crack and see if they are running into the same problem or provide any suggestions?

Comment: The package maintainer mentions having to [manually install the SQLite extension from the SQLite website][1] and earlier from the [visualstudio gallery][2] in the issues tracker. Maybe give that a go? 


  [1]: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/250
  [2]: https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8/issues/14

Comment: I have the same problem and I didn't found any solution, did you found one ?

Answer (score 1):

Tim Heuer gives step by step instructions [ON THIS LINK](https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=A737583042956228!1940&cid=a737583042956228&app=OneNote&wdo=2).  The batch files are hardcoded for TCL 8.5, you'll save yourself some time if you don't download the latest (8.6)

EDITED - I successfully compiled SQLite with Tim's steps (I just reinstalled Windows 8.1 / VS 2013).   Note: the only issue I encountered was taking the steps to literally, be sure to change into the newly created SQLite directory before running the fossil command.

FYI for WinRT, be sure to use the correct path, if you just specify the filename you will get an access denied error (which will surface as a "cannot open database" error).

```
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace std;

void SqliteWrapper::RunTest(void)
{
sqlite3 *db;
int rc;

auto path = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path+"\\MyDatabase.db";
string dataPath(path->Begin(), path->End());
rc = sqlite3_open(dataPath.c_str(), &db);

if( rc ){
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
  sqlite3_close(db);
}

sqlite3_close(db);
}
```